# How do i get rid of the border around my header image

Tags: image, header

How can I get rid of the white box covering my header image?

http://bentleyandhudson.com

Answer (score 0):

The color of your background is also white... So changing that color would make it look a bit weird...

But if you do want to, add this to your css and change the color code.

```
.site-header-wrapper {
    background-color: #ffffff; // this is white, but change it to any colour you want.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help however I didn't make it clear! I wanted to get rid of the white box thats over the top of the image of the two dogs in the woods... How would I do that?

Comment: @Annabelle Try removing the padding (and perhaps margins if you want to) from `.site-title-wrapper`.

Comment: Don't remove it, change it. Change the padding from 3% 1rem to 3% 0. Also remove both margin-left and margin-right. That would give you the result you want.